# how to limit the boundary limits in draggable according to screen size?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-draggable

i have a background image in a container with same width as the background image .. I have set draggable function for the container..i want to limit the drag function with 20px in all the sides..

[MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DGbT3/1528/)

> Script

```
$('#dragThis').draggable(
    {
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;
            $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);

  }
});
```

[image: Initial state when background and container are each other]
[image: State when background image is shifted/dragged i want to limit the drag]
[image: same distance in all the sides]
[image: limit after this]
[image: same distance in all the sides]

Answer (score 1):

what you can do it.. create a parent of the div which you want to drag..

parent(20px larger in all the side from draggable)
child div which you want to drag, set the

**containment :"parent"** it will work for you.. 
check it [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DGbT3/1529/)

As I have update you jquery part ..

```
    containment: "parent",
```

and set the parent **div id=contain** height and width little larger then the draggable child.

now you can drag in parent div boundary only..